# Java socket programming fails to close the connection gracefully

Tags: java, tcp, serversocket

I implemented a web server using Java socket programing. It works fine. Only problem is when I analyze the packet trace in Wireshark, the connection is not being closed properly with a FIN, ACK FIN, ACK sequence.

I have tested with all possible combinations of flushing and closing the streams and sockets but the protocol fails.

[image: Packets 46, 47 and 48 show the problem]

The good trace should look like this one:

[image: Python implementation performs better]

Following is the server code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class WebServer3  {
    public static void main (String args[]) //throws Exception
    {
        try{
            //========== Server Starts ===========
            int serverPort = 80;
            ServerSocket listenSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort);
            System.out.println("Server listening on socket..."+listenSocket);
            while(true) {
                Socket clientSocket = listenSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Created client socket: "+clientSocket);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                
                // Wite output response
                OutputStream output = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
                //PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                output.write(("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" + "Content-Type: text/html" + "\r\n\r\n").getBytes());
                byte[] fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("index.html"));
                String fileString = new String(fileBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                
                //output.write(fileString);
                output.write(fileBytes);
                System.out.println("Finished writing content to output");
                output.flush();
                System.out.println("Finished writing content to output");
                output.close();
                System.out.println("Finished writing content to output");
                br.close();
                System.out.println("Finished writing content to output");
                
                //output.flush();
                //System.out.println("Response sent");
                //clientSocket.close(); //terminating connection

                //output.flush();
                //br.close();
                //output.close();
                //clientSocket.close();
                
                //url.close();
                //clientSocket.close();
                //output.close();
                //br.close();// HTTP is response is not sent back
                //clientSocket.close();
                
            }// While
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Listen :"+e.getMessage());
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }//main
}
```

My question is what sequence should be followed to gracefully close the connection? There are numerous codes on internet but none is found to meet the demand.

Comment: Have you tried first reading all data from the sockets `InputStream` (`br`), then outputing all data using and then closing (just) the `OutputStream` (`output`)? Note that the socket remains a server socket, `clientSocket = listenSocket.accept()` makes no sense to me.

Comment: TCP resets usually mean that one end has closed the connection while the other end is still sending, or when it still had unread pending data. In other words, an application protocol error. In this case you haven't read the HTTP request,.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes It makes sense to me. You will find that line of code in every Java TCP server ever written. I don't know what you mean by 'note that the socket remains a server socket'.

Comment: This is the server side, right? So there is no "client socket". The client socket is on the client, not the server?

Comment: @AbuBakar Any kind of information that is not part of the question is considered spurious. This goes for all text, including "thank you" statements and similar constructs, but also calls to any kind of gods. I did do some other edits as well, but if you think I missed any *then why didn't you fix them yourself*?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes ignorance about one's creator is the biggest of all ignorances.
 This is not a duplicate question. The question you linked asks a generic socket. Mine is specific about TCP Web socket. My considerable time was consumed diagnosing that "NULL" is never received in GET query. Rather end of response is checked by "\r\n\r\n". That question checks for "Null" which would never arrive and program would hang.

Comment: Since you are closing the question, next person will have to figure it out on his own. 

Client socket is used because it provides getInputStream() and getOutputStream() methods to communicate. How would data read and written using the server socket? See the two class methods:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html

I did correct omissions in my question (before your comment arrived). I expect a better moderator for stack exchange.

Comment: This is a programming site, if any god wants to participate they are free to post, but otherwise they are off topic, and spurious text  *of any kind* is subject to be removed. First of all, please pay attention: I did not close the question, I just hinted and apparently I hinted correctly. `Socket` is not named `ClientSocket` for a reason, it represents any socket, client **or** server. On the server you only have server sockets (usually sockets with specific static port numbers). On the client you'd have (usually dynamic) port numbers.